# WCF Rest SSL HTTPS simple GET

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, ssl

when creating this topic I saw quite a few unanswered ones hopefully someone can help me out here.

- I have a simple WCF Service hosted in IIS.
- I have associated this "website" with a self assigned certificate
- I can a html page within it and forces me to proceed to page (localhost test.htm)

I want to access a restful service and I am using Fiddler to mock a request:

```
GET > https://localhost/company/get
```

Request Headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Authorization: Joe;Bloggs
```

Get an error 404.0 Not Found. I imagine I am doing a schoolboy?

Thanks in advance, Onam.

WCF Code:

```
public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
{
    public IEnumerable<Integration.Business.Objects.Company> Get()
    {
        List<Integration.Business.Objects.Company> c = new List<Integration.Business.Objects.Company>();
        c.Add(new Integration.Business.Objects.Company() { Name = "Blah" });
        return c;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ICompanyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "company/get")]
    IEnumerable<Integration.Business.Objects.Company> Get();
}
```

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="CompanyService"
               behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehaviour_Mango">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_Mango"
                  behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehaviour_Mango"
                  contract="ICompanyService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttpBehaviour_Mango">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_Mango">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
         </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry giving you a trial and error .... try to confirm the security exception by forcefully adding SSL either through IE or FF n then try?

Comment: Another mention , I see you have kept the endpoint address to auto generate, check what address the wcf service is hosted from IIS?

Comment: I set the endpoint address in the config and tried but still didn't work :(

Comment: Does the http protocol work correctly?

Comment: could you try to make the request just through IE first and see what response you get? If you try http://localhost/company/get/help do you see the webmethod listed?                          <endpointBehaviors>
   <behavior name="WebHttpBehaviour_Mango">
      <webHttp enableHelp="true"/>
   </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

Comment: are you using a .svc file for the WCF service or using a Route Table to define a path to the REST service? If you are using a .svc file you would need to get the correct URL as https://localhost/sample.svc/company/get (or) if you are using RouteTable then https://localhost/routetablepath/company/get should get you going

Comment: Using an svc file. I found that the url had to be exactly what you stated Rajesh which is with the company.svc/company/get. Looking to remove that out. Thanks all.